# Aggregation in java

Tags: java, aggregate-functions

I've following code

file a.java

```
class ABC {
    public void printing(DEF def, GHI ghi)
    {
        def.test();
        ghi.test2();
    }
}

class DEF {
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("as");
    }
}

class GHI {
    public void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("dsfg");
    }
}
```

then i've another file, let's call it file b.java, how can I create object from class DEF and GHI on file b.java?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?  (i.e. what is your best attempt so far at writing b.java?)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use import statement.

If both files are in same package you don't have to import anything. If both are in different packages, use import statements with package.
Example:

if a.java is in *com.demo* package, use `import com.demo.*;` in b.java

By the way, if you are using Netbeans or eclipse, you don't have to do anything, IDE will automatically import those classes in ur b.java.

Then you can create objects for classes you want.

**EDIT**

**UPDATE 2**

Example:

```
DEF def= new DEF();
GHI ghi= new GHI();
```

Now you can use the mthods of those two classes.

```
def.test();
ghi.test();
```

Comment: Will this work. Is it compiling for you. OP is not talking about Outer and Inner class.

Comment: I have edited. Please check it. @Jayamohan where is your b.java? what have you tried there?

Comment: it's on the same package, but it doesn't work with "DEF = new DEF()" too.

Comment: oh!! thanks for noticing this... I didn't created an object. You have to create an object. sorry... Check the update again

Comment: ah, yeah, you're right. It's only my stupidity from the beginning. I got the error only because wrong parameter. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
a a1 = new a();
DEF = a1.new DEF();
GHI = a1.new GHI();
```

Or

```
DEF def  = new a().new DEF();
GHI ghi = new a().new GHI();
```

This will work fine if it is in the same `package`, if not you should `import`.

Comment: Will this work. Is it compiling for you. OP is  not talking about Outer and Inner class.